# How to create an overlay for app as an watermark in Android pragmatically?

Tags: android, android-overlay, android-app-watermark

I want to make an app in which there will be a watermark that will be shown in every activity including the fragments if it exists. I want to do that programmatically, without any XML for reducing redundant and boilerplate code.
The main purpose of it is that if I share an APK with anyone else then he cannot steal my APK because it contains a weird watermark everywhere.

Comment: I know actually how to add watermark in an image but i really want to add this in an activity whatever It contains image or other views .

Comment: You can implement a base activity which add a watermark  view to root content view automatically then extend this base activity from all other Activities

Comment: Then it will be like a background image.But i want just an overlay.

Comment: If you add the watermark view on top of root view, how can it be a background image?

Comment: I tried it already and it causes  many "On click listener" issues .

Comment: Actually My requirement was that https://github.com/Gkemon/App-Watermark/blob/master/watermark.gif and I made it windows manager.  @DuyKhanhNguyen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made a [library](https://github.com/Gkemon/App-Watermark) for this to do that in a reusable way. Here is documentation on how to use it in [Java](https://github.com/Gkemon/App-Watermark#by-java) and [Kotlin](https://github.com/Gkemon/App-Watermark#by-kotlin). First, initialize it from an activity from where you want to show the watermark-

```
AppWaterMarkBuilder.doConfigure()
                .setAppCompatActivity(MainActivity.this)
                .setWatermarkProperty(R.layout.layout_water_mark)
                .showWatermarkAfterConfig();
```

Then you can hide and show it from anywhere in your app -

```
  /* For hiding the watermark without callback*/
  AppWaterMarkBuilder.hideWatermark() 

  /* For showing the watermark without callback*/
  AppWaterMarkBuilder.showWatermark()
```

[image: preview]

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a canvas object then draw on top of that. Canvas would be of size of the screen and so you can then measure the size for watermark bitmap. Then render it as a background image in the activity.

Comment: Will it create a problem in click event?

Comment: will not be create problem. if it will create problem then put this code.  "image.setEnabled(false);"

Comment: Actually My requirement was that https://github.com/Gkemon/App-Watermark/blob/master/watermark.gif and I made it windows manager.